# Using ClassTag/TypeTag instead of ClassManifest in Scala 2.10

Tags: scala, scala-2.10

I have some code to instantiate a random class like this:

```
trait T
class A extends T
class B extends T
class C extends T

def createRandomT = {
    val choices = Vector(classOf[A], classOf[B], classOf[C])
    val cls = new scala.util.Random().shuffle(choices).head
    instantiateT(cls)
}                                   

def instantiateT(cls: Class[_ <: T]) = {
    ClassManifest.fromClass(cls) match {
        case c if c <:< classManifest[A] => new A
        case c if c <:< classManifest[B] => new B
        case c if c <:< classManifest[C] => new C
    }
}
```

This works, but after upgrading to 2.10 `instantiateT` gives various deprecation warnings.

Any hints how to replicate the functionality with `ClassTag` and/or `TypeTag`?

**Edit:** As pointed out by Daniel this works:

```
    cls match {
        case c if c.isAssignableFrom(classOf[A]) => new A
        case c if c.isAssignableFrom(classOf[B]) => new B
        case c if c.isAssignableFrom(classOf[C]) => new C
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've got a `Class`, you should just use `isAssignableFrom`.

```
case c if cls.isAssignableFrom(c.getClass()) => new A
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why it has to be so complicated...
Surely if you already have a `Class` instance you can just call `Class.newInstance`? Like so:

```
def instantiateT(cls: Class[_ <: T]) = cls.newInstance
```

Or maybe you are performing a match because in your real code each class has a separate list of (default) argument to pass to the constructor?

Comment: Yes, you're right, the real code is somewhat more involved with constructing the instances.